# Help with remapping control to escape using xmodmap?

Tags: arch-linux, x-server, xmodmap

So I'm currently using this to achieve

1. CapsLock + *Anykey* = Control + *Anykey*
2. Shift + CapsLock = CapsLock

```
clear lock
clear control
add control = Caps_Lock Control_L Control_R
keycode 66 = Control_L Caps_Lock NoSymbol NoSymbol
```

I got this from the ArchWiki page for [xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap), but I want to go one step further and make it such that CapsLock by itself is mapped to Escape. Is it possible to do this? I tried understanding the syntax for xmodmap but couldn't figure it out.

Edit:
Just to be clear, this is what I finally wish to achieve:

1. CapsLock + *Anykey* = Control + *Anykey*
2. Shift + CapsLock = CapsLock
3. CapsLock = Escape

Comment: Then maybe `keycode 66 = Escape Caps_Lock NoSymbol NoSymbol`?

Comment: @Quasimodo Thank-you, this seems to have achieved what I want :D

Comment: Oh, your edit is clear now. Although you say it works, I don't think point 1 will be working with my suggestion, and neither can I help with that.

Comment: @Quasimodo Actually, Capslock + *Anykey* = Control + *Anykey* does work as expected for me, with the exception of Caplock + *ArrowKeys* for some reason.